# URL Rewriting - how to configure multiple domain on same website with http and https

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I have a one website application pointing multiple domains.

what i want is, if user visiting domain1.com then they should be redirect to **https**://www.domain1.com

and rest all domain pointing same application use **without https** (e.g **http**://www.domain2.com / **http**://www.domain3.com)

Domain must redirect as below:

1. domain1.com > https://www.domain1.com
2. domain2.com > http://www.domain2.com (rewrite as below code)
3. domain3.com > http://www.domain3.com (rewrite as below code)

Below code to rewrite for other than https domains.

```
<rule name="domain1" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^www.domain1.com$" negate="true" />          
   <action type="Rewrite" url="otherdomain/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Appriciate your help in advance. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below configuration?

```
<rules>
    <rule name="Remove WWW prefix" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.domain1\.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain1.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
```

Comment: Did you add binding at IIS level? Where does the site redirects?

Comment: No, i am updating same on server with my live domain hosting.

Comment: Can you please add the binding and try?